# Xamarin Forms Shell - iOS extend view under bottom TabBar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-forms-shell

I am trying to extend my pages from my Shell under the bottom tabbar in iOS

**MyShellRenderer:ShellRenderer** class

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]
 namespace your namepace
 {
   class MyShellRenderer:ShellRenderer
   {
      protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
      {
          return new MyShellTabBarAppearanceTrancker();
      }
   }
 }
```

**MyShellTabBarAppearanceTrancker** class:

```
class MyShellTabBarAppearanceTrancker : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
    {
      
    }

    public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
       controller.TabBar.IsTranslucent = true;        
    }

    public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
    {
        
    }
}
```

But it does not work, the Shell keep all pages above the bottom tabbar (like in a stacklayout).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Alpha` instead of `IsTranslucent`  .

The value of this property is a floating-point number in the range 0.0 to 1.0, where 0.0 represents totally transparent and 1.0 represents totally opaque.

Try to set it as  `controller.TabBar.Alpha = 0.5f;` .

#### Test code in xaml

```
   <Grid>
        <Label Text="111" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        <Label Text="222" Margin="30,0,0,-50" VerticalOptions="End"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: idk how but it does not works for me :/ Is it possible to accomplish this in a renderer without having to put transparency ?

Comment: without having to put transparency ? What does that mean ?

Comment: opaque bar (with solid color), i explain why i want to achieve this : because  i added rounded corner (top left and top right) to the tabbar but the view is above the tabbar, so the rendering is bad and the solution is the view should pass under the tabbar